# SQL Inner Join with data modification to fill empty columns

Tags: sql

I'm considering the following columns in two tables, where the clicks_ columns are empty and should be filled with data learned from the mwhen and mwho columns. The join should be on mwho and user_id.

**Students**

user_id, clicks_jan, clicks_feb, clicks_mar, clicks_apr

**Usage**

mwho, mwhen

My questions:

1. Do I need a select statement, or can I move immediately from "UPDATE students" to set (...) to update the columns?
2. SQL complains when I ask it to pull info from both tables at once to perform the calculation - at least, it does when I state "FROM students, usage". Is there a clear workaround to update one table with modified info from another?

An abridged version of what I have so far. (Since the column updates are all similar, I only show one here for example.)

```
update students

set clicks_jan = 

    sum(
        case 
        when cast(strftime('%j', mwhen) as integer) < 32 then 1
        else 0 end)
from students, usage 
inner join students.user_id = usage.mwho;
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly what you are trying but here is my stab at it:

```
UPDATE students set
  Clicks_jan = (SELECT case when cast(strftime('%j',mwhen) AS integer) < 32
                            then 1 else 0 end
                FROM usage
                WHERE mwho=student.user_id);
```

Comment: Thanks! I made a small alteration to get it the way I wanted:  Clicks_jan = ( sum( when cast(strftime('%j',mwhen) AS integer) < 32
                            then 1 else 0 end)
                FROM usage
                WHERE mwho=student.user_id);